# Populate This Multidimensional array with for or foreach

Tags: php

I have this array but I do not know how to populate it dynamically

My code:

```
 for ($j = 1; $j <= $weeks; $j++)
    { 
        for ($i = 1; $i <= 7; $i++)
        {
            $turn_data = $request->input('turn_'.$i.'_'.$j);

            if(isset($turn_data))
            {
                $turn_data = explode("_", $turn_data);

                $turn = Turn::find($turn_data[0]);

                if($day < 10)
                {
                    $day = "0".$day;
                }

                $data = array("apiKey" => "85526dd10b9aa01ae6e56698b848d191",
                    "turnos" => [["codigo" => $rut, 
                    "nombreTurno" => $turn->name, 
                    "fechaInicio" => $year."-".$month_detail_number."-".$day." 00:00:00", 
                    "fechaTermino" => $year."-".$month_detail_number."-".$day." 23:59:59"]]);
            }

            $day = $day + 1;
        }
    }
```

How can I put the array? The problem is that turnos is an array too, that's my problem

I need an output like this:

```
Array ( [apiKey] => 85526dd10b9aa01ae6e56698b848d191 [turnos] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [codigo] => 15918421 [nombreTurno] => 6x1 FT/ 08:30 a 16:00 [fechaInicio] => 2019-12-13 00:00:00 [fechaTermino] => 2019-12-13 23:59:59 ) ) )
```

Thanks!

Comment: How do you want the output array?

Comment: Hey, please may you clarify a couple of things? What does the output currently looklike and how do you want it to look?

Comment: _“The problem is that turnos is an array too, that's my problem”_ - and _how exactly_ is it a problem? Very unclear what you are trying to ask here. Start by showing a proper example of what you _want_ the result look like maybe.

Comment: Wild guess: Your `$data` array is actually just supposed to have a single dimension, with two keys `apiKey` and `turnos` - and only `turnos` itself is supposed to be a multi-dimensional array, that you add stuff to in each loop iteration …? Well then you should stop _overwriting_ $data in each iteration first of all.

Comment: The output that I need: Array ( [apiKey] => 85526dd10b9aa01ae6e56698b848d191 [turnos] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [codigo] => 15918421 [nombreTurno] => 6x1 FT/ 08:30 a 16:00 [fechaInicio] => 2019-12-13 00:00:00 [fechaTermino] => 2019-12-13 23:59:59 ) ) )

Comment: So create $data before the loops, so that it contains `apiKey` and respective value, and `turnos` as an empty array already. And then add new elements only to `$data['turnos']` in your loops: `$data['turnos'][] = ['codigo' => $rut, …];`